# Mongo $push operator do not accept object according to typescript: "No overload matches this call"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I want to push a message in an array with Mongoose/Mongo. Typescript claims that:

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 3, '(id: any, update: UpdateQuery, options: QueryOptions & { rawResult: true; }, callback?: ((err: any, doc: FindAndModifyWriteOpResultObject, res: any) => void) | undefined): any', gave the following error.
> Type '{ messages: { message: string; authorId: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'PushOperator<_AllowStringsForIds<Pick<Pick<_LeanDocument, string | number | symbol>, string | number | symbol>>>'.
> Type '{ messages: { message: string; authorId: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'NotAcceptedFields<_AllowStringsForIds<Pick<Pick<_LeanDocument, string | number | symbol>, string | number | symbol>>, readonly any[]>'.
> Property 'messages' is incompatible with index signature.

Here is the code snippet:

```js
    const conversation = await Conversation.findByIdAndUpdate(
      conversationId,
      {
        $push: { messages: { message, authorId } },
        lastMessage: {
          authorId,
          snippet: `${message.substring(0, 47)}...`,
          read: false,
        },
      },
      { new: true }
    );
```

The build crash because of this. How to fix it?

Comment: Read the documentation for correct usage, if you think your usage is correct link to relevant documentation showing it.

Comment: Could you please correct my code? I've read the doc https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate but I don't see where I make any mistake.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with your code but you should reduce it to figure that out.

Comment: I am writing a question on stackoverflow because I am looking for an answer. You just show up and say "go read the doc. I don't know how to fix your problem, just debug it."... I don't see your point. Anyways, thanks for swinging by this thread, have a great day.

Comment: SO is a place to get answers to specific questions. It is not a place to get someone else to debug complete programs.

Comment: This question is about a typescript error on 12 lines of code. I am not asking anyone to debug a whole program.

Comment: @D.SM, this is a pretty ridiculous take. SO is *exactly* the place for this kind of question. The OP isn't asking for someone to 'debug complete programs', he's asking what seems like a pretty specific question about an issue with TypeScript types and Mongo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with types not lining up.

My understanding is the push operation can only be done on a field that is explicitly defined as an array at some point in your code previously.

A potential solution is to explicitly set the type of your collection to contain the fields you want (which is good practice anyway).

So rather than something along the lines of

```
const Conversations = database.collection('conversations');
```

You would explicitly define the schema for the 'conversation' documents, and then type the collection:

```
import { Collection } from 'mongodb';
//...
type Conversation = {
  messages: { message: String, authorId: Number }[],
//...
}

const Conversations: Collection<Conversation> = database.collection('conversations');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know you're doing the right thing, then you can bypass this with `as`.

The following example illustrates this.

```
await driver.collection('myCollection').findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        _id: "<some _id that I have>",
    },
    {
        '$push': {
            'myArrayField': {
                '$position': 0,
                '$each': [ myItemToPush ],
             }
         } as unknown as PushOperator<Document>,
     },
     {
         returnDocument: 'after',
         upsert: false,
     },
 );
```

Note the `as unknown as PushOperator<Document>` - this is what's going to get you out of this problem. Use it properly as Tyscript will allow you to use `as` anywhree and used unabated, this can defeat the purpose of using a type system.